# From where is the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY read?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, webjob

From where is the InstrumentationKey read?

```
context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
```

I have put that key in the applicationInsights.config in the section

```
  <InstrumentationKey>94efb022-e651-46a0-b103-5735daa213f1</InstrumentationKey>
```

but its not taken from there...

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                {
                    // Add extensions and other WebJobs services
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
                {
                    // Add configuration sources          
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    // Add Logging Providers
                    b.AddConsole();

                    // If this key exists in any config, use it to enable App Insights
                    string appInsightsKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
                    {
                        // This uses the options callback to explicitly set the instrumentation key.
                        b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
                    }
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it on Azure just set it in the `Application Settings` in the Portal.

And if you are running it locally, in the `appsettings.json` file add  `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` field there.

```
{
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{storage connection string}",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "{instrumentation key}"
}
```

Further more information, refer to this doc :[Add Application Insights logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#add-application-insights-logging). Hope this could help you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install below packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights (Currently in beta)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

and Configure **`JobHostConfiguration`** as below:

```
string instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
{
      // build up a LoggerFactory with ApplicationInsights and a Console Logger
       config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null).AddConsole();
       config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;
}
```

You can read about configuration application insight with Azure web job [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration). Hope it helps.